# Registering my application to URI Scheme and fetching the command that launched it

Tags: windows, winapi, uri, url-scheme

Windows allows me to register my application to a URI Scheme as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)). If the application is already running clicking on the URI should bring it to the foreground. For some reason, GetCommandLineW() keeps giving me the original command that launched the application.
Is there some way I could get the new URI that brought my window to the foreground.

I'm aware [Win messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-app) could be used to get the command line arguments. Is there some way to associate my URI commands with a win message.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp]
@="URL:myapp"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\DefaultIcon]
@="<Path To App>,2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell\open\command]
@="\"<Path To App>" \"%1\""
```

Comment: When you register a URI scheme you can specify an app that gets run when the URI is triggered, that app can do anything it wants including sending a message to another window.

Comment: @JonathanPotter What I want is for the app to retrieve the command line that launched it. If the app is already running I want the last command that was run which brings it to the foreground. Updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: *"that app can do anything it wants"* including parsing its command line arguments and passing it to the running instance, prior to bringing the running instance to the foreground and terminating. I don't understand how window messages were to be used to get command line arguments.

Comment: So you have two separate problems you need to solve; finding an existing instance of your application, and passing a string to it once found. Neither are specific to custom URI schemes.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Well actually my application finds an existing instance and returns it. This is done when it receives a WM_ACTIVATEAPP message when I run the URI from "Run" window. What I want is for it to capture the URI command that triggered that message.

Comment: @Zeeshan you don't seem to be grasping what is required here. The way you have registered the URL scheme, when a new URL is executed, A NEW INSTANCE of your program is launched, with the new URL in its command line. THAT NEW PROCESS is responsible to then LOOK FOR A PREVIOUS INSTANCE, and if found then SEND the new URL to that instance via any IPC mechanism you want, it doesn't have to be a window message, but that is certainly the easiest way (ie, via `WM_COPYDATA`), and then exit itself.

Comment: @Zeeshan If you don't want to handle it this way, then you can instead register your URL scheme to use [DDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/about-dynamic-data-exchange), and then implement a DDE server in your program. Whenever a new URL is executed, Windows will send the new URL directly to your DDE server if it is active, otherwise it will launch a new instance of your program. See [How to Associate Verbs with DDE Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-associate-verbs-with-dde-commands)

Comment: @Zeeshan "*If the command is already running clicking on the URI should bring it to the foreground.*" Where you click the URI and how do you launch your application in the pluggable protocol handler? Can you show difference between URI that launched your app and URI that brought your window to the foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks a lot everyone for your comments. Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie and it took me some time to grasp what was being stated from the beginning. I'll leave this comment here in case someone wants to check back.

As suggested, my app did launch a new window. It found an instance of my app that was already running. And as a result terminated.
What I changed? Before this newly launched instance is terminated, I send a new message to the previously running instance of my application. In order to pass the contents of the command line I used [named shared memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

The receiving app just listened to this message. On receiving it, it retrieves the command line from the shared memory and allows me to handle the command line.

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution. You can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).